# Why I run "ssh username@ip 'bash test.sh'" in my shell but it gets stuck?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tmux

here is my **test.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux kill-session -t django
tmux new-session -s django -d
tmux send-keys -t django "cd ~/DialogueRobot/DiaRobot" C-m
tmux send-keys -t django "conda activate robot" C-m
tmux send-keys -t django "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" C-m
```

i have checked my server by running `tmux ls` and `test.sh` actually works.

but it just can't exit when i run `ssh username@ip 'bash test.sh'` in local shell unless i input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

i can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: This can happen if you start a process on the remote system which continues to run after the remote shell session ends. If the remote process has the ssh session as its standard output, the remote ssh server will hold the connection open.

Comment: BTW, if you're running on a modern system with a proper init system, you don't need to use tmux to run programs and review their logs later -- systemd is very widespread, and supports "user services" where folks without root can define their own background services, with journaled logs available just like system services have. Some other init systems you'd need a sysadmin's help to set up your own service with, but _getting_ that help will get you something vastly more reliably than playing around with tmux.

Comment: (a properly supervised service is automatically restarted if it fails, automatically restarted on reboot -- if configured to be -- can have dependencies declared so it starts them up if they're down and doesn't _try_ to start until they've been brought up, etc etc)

Comment: thank you very much，i will try to use systemd to start my service